# WPF Buttons don't change when pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using Windows 8 and getting my feet wet with WPF and one of the things that is bugging me is that buttons don't change color when they are being pressed like they would in a WinForms program.

I tried searching and oddly enough I can't see anyone else discussing this so I almost think it's something specific with my setup although as far as I can tell I haven't changed anything that would do this.

The button changes color when I hover over it and when I click it doesn't change, it still looks like I am just hovering.
Is this what it is supposed to do and if so what is the best way to override this and still respect the user's theme colors?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
To demonstrate what I mean [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CJBS.png) are screen shots showing a standard button in Windows 7 compared to Windows 8. What I am trying to figure out is how to make WPF button in Windows 8 behave like any other button and make it look like the button is getting pressed in when you press it.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so that we can help you. You change color in code behind or use trigger?

Comment: Almost three years later, I am wondering the same thing. In fact, they _do_ change when pressed, very, very slightly. You can confirm this with screen captures and sampling the pixels, or by editing a copy of the template. It's amazing to me that anyone would set two different colors for those two different states, yet choose two colors so close as to be indistinguishable. I can't image what the person who made that decision thought they were doing. Only fix I know is to copy and modify the template. It works, but why should I have do that?