# Why do WPF buttons change so slightly when pressed?

Tags: wpf, button

The question of how to make a WPF button change appearance when pressed has been spoken to here on SO before. However, hoping this question is still SO-appropriate, I'm wondering if anyone know why it changes so little. After all my years as a coder, I have learned enough humility to think that, if I find myself struggling to change the basic behavior of a professional product, it is possible that I don't understand the product as well as I should.

What's particularly baffling to me is that the on-screen appearance of a WPF button *does* change when it is pressed. Here's a WPF button when the mouse is hovering over it:

[image: WPF button not being pressed, in "MouseOver" state]

And here's that button with the mouse button held down during a click:

[image: WPF button being pressed, in "Pressed" state]

At first glance, they look the same, but they're not. Sampling the pixels in those screencaps confirms what you can also glean by editing a copy of the button's WPF template: the "MouseOver" state fills the background with 0xBEE6FD (that is, red=0xBE, green=0xE6, and blue=0xFD), while the "Pressed" state fills the background with 0xC4F5E6. (Numerically, that's a distance of about 0.11 in the RGB color space, normalized to a [0,1] range on each axis, and no more than 0.09 on any of those axes.)

It would almost make more sense if the button's appearance did not change at all when pressed. That would be consistent with a lot of buttons one presses on Web pages (or do they change too, and it is also by a slight amount, and I've just not noticed it?). But, here, someone made the specific decision to alter the appearance of a button between those two, typically successive, states, but only by a very little bit, arguably too small to even see.

Why would a person make that choice?

I recognize that asking questions that call for opinion is against SO policy, so I hope I can be a bit strict about what I'm requesting: does anyone actually know why WPF buttons change appearance so slightly when they transition from "MouseOver" to "Pressed" state? In particular, has it been addressed by anything published by Microsoft? (Googling for this answer proves problematic, as most of the results I find are about how to edit the style or template so as to make the change in appearance much greater, not why it works this way to begin with.)

Thanks to anyone who can help me understand what I may have been missing here.

Comment: You can modify how much it changes on a button press. I have no idea why you would even ask such a question really.

Comment: I know you can change it. I tried to explain my purpose in asking.

Comment: I would say the reason is rather obvious. States which are of low relevance, e.g being hovered or pressed, should result in less distraction, whereas a deactivated button obviously should stand out.

Comment: The Windows theme affects this. My buttons with the default Win7 theme look very different to yours.

Comment: Thanks, @EdPlunkett, that's helpful. I have tried other themes (I should have mentioned I'm on Windows 10), but they don't make much difference. Dbl, your reasoning is hard for me to follow. Isn't there a significant relevance to a button being pressed, versus not being pressed?

Comment: @EdPlunkett, are you actually running Windows 7? Apparently, the behavior changed after that (in Windows 8). [This unanswered SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691552/wpf-buttons-dont-change-when-pressed) took notice of that.

Comment: @StevensMiller Win7 Pro SP1, FWIW.

Comment: Ah, there you go! For some reason, this was a deliberate change from one version of the OS's default theme to the next. It's quite baffling to me as, though he seems not to get his own point, Dbl is right: a significant change in state calls for an appearance that stands out. Yet MS went in exactly the opposite direction. I just downloaded a few other themes and none of them affects this (well, the high contrast themes restore the old Win95 pseudo-3D animation effect). Again, @EdPlunkett I am left wondering if this is now considered a best practice and I just don't know why.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a good answer to that one. Why did Windows 8 try to turn everything into a phone app? Why did Napoleon invade Russia? My impression of the state of things at Microsoft is that it's a senescent company and UX decisions are increasingly affected by people who have no business anywhere near those decisions.

Comment: [This essay was written 11 years ago](http://moishelettvin.blogspot.com.ar/2006/11/windows-shutdown-crapfest.html). It describes a state of corporate entropy that won't have reversed itself without some kind of deus ex machina like Steve Jobs rising from the grave and taking over, which we'd have heard about.

Comment: Thanks again, @EdPlunkett. That essay actually is somewhat illuminating. You're right, of course. The only answer to most questions that start with "Why..." tends to be "Because." That's why I tried to be more specific and ask if MS had ever stated a reason. All else is mere speculation, but they do, from time to time, explain themselves. (SO is warning me against extended discussions now, so we can talk further in chat if you like. Again, your input has been most welcomed.)